# How to select first item in recyclerview

Tags: android

Suppose I have selected position 3 in recyclerview when I navigate to previous page and come again I want the frist item of recyclerview to be selected

```
    int selectposition = 0;


if (selectedPosition == position ) {
            chckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            chckbox.setChecked(true);
            chckbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkbox_selector);
            chckbox.forceLayout();
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_address_bg);

        } else {
            chckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            chckbox.setChecked(false);
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }
```

Comment: pass position index onload on activity

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days I got final solution as below:

```
// Make your Adapter...
mLeftAdapter = new LeftMenuAdapter(mContext, mFilterValuesArray);

// Bind it to RecyclerView
mFilterBinding.filterLeftRecyclerView.setAdapter(mLeftAdapter);

//Call this method which will perform click for 0'th position after computing (binding) all data...
postAndNotifyAdapter(new Handler(), mFilterBinding.filterLeftRecyclerView);
```

**postAndnotifyAdapter** method will be like:

```
protected void postAndNotifyAdapter(final Handler handler, final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!recyclerView.isComputingLayout()) {
                // This will call first item by calling "performClick()" of view.
                ((LeftMenuAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(0)).mView.performClick();
            } else {
                postAndNotifyAdapter(handler, recyclerView, adapter);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

May this will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In onBind method,make the first position selected,so that everytime when you go back to another activity and again come back,first item will be selected.

```
if(position == 0){
chckbox.setChecked(true);
chckbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkbox_selector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the first position by following code:
You can replace with your layout Manager

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```